# How to show modal after validation of form?

Tags: javascript

I want that after submission of form and check empty field(validation) a message(on modal) will popup with message "Fill out all the form!". How to do this? I tried but it doesn't show error but it also not running. If anyone know please tell what is missing or correct it how to do this.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    function signup(){
    var fName=document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
    var mobile=document.getElementById("nMobile").value;

    if(fName=="" || email=="" || password=="" || mobile==""){
    $("#valdMsg").modal("show");
    }
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="valdMsg" tabindex="-1" role="modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5>Warning!</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        Fill out all forms.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <label for="txtName">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail"/>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtPassword"/>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <label for="nMobile">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="nMobile"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" id="sign_up" onclick="signup()">
    Sign Up
    </button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: `$("#valdMsg").modal("show");`

Comment: formValidation.js:148 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at signup (formValidation.js:148)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):163)

Comment: Why you import Jquery two times ? Similarly Whether using </body> is typo or did you really made mistake in it .Please check it out

Comment: Thanxxx dude...My typo mistake not allow me to trigger modal. Very Very thanx

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Dont Use multiple JQuery Instance in your file
> 2. Please check your Jquery file,Some CDN files Wont Work Properly
> 3. Please always keep in mind that order of import ,First we have to import jquery then only we need to import all other Javascript library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from points mentioned by @vasanth, i've changed button type from submit to button, that has resolved the issue

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <label for="txtName">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="txtEmail" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtPassword" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <label for="nMobile">Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="number" id="nMobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" id="sign_up" onclick="signup()">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="modal" id="valdMsg" tabindex="-1" role="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Warning!</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Fill out all forms.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function signup() {
            var fName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
            var mobile = document.getElementById("nMobile").value;

            if (!fName || !email || !password || !mobile) {
                $("#valdMsg").modal();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

note: It is trying to submit form after opening modal thats y modal is getting closed

---

---